# How to unpack and pack pkg file?

Tags: macos, pkg-file

I have a pkg file created by Install Maker for Mac.
I want to replace one file in pkg. But I must do this under Linux system, because this is a part of download process. When user starts to download file server must replace one file in pkg.
I have a solution how unpack pkg and replace a file but I dont know how pack again to pkg.
http://emresaglam.com/blog/1035
http://ilostmynotes.blogspot.com/2012/06/mac-os-x-pkg-bom-files-package.html

Comment: (For future visitors) http://gabrielrinaldi.me/how-to-install-jdk-7-on-yosemite-10-10/ might give you insight

Comment: MacOS appears to come with the xar command.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Packages are just .xar archives with a different extension and a specified file hierarchy. Unfortunately, part of that file hierarchy is a cpio.gz archive of the actual installables, and usually that's what you want to edit. And there's also a Bom file that includes information on the files inside that cpio archive, and a PackageInfo file that includes summary information.

If you really do just need to edit one of the info files, that's simple:

```
mkdir Foo
cd Foo
xar -xf ../Foo.pkg
# edit stuff
xar -cf ../Foo-new.pkg *
```

But if you need to edit the installable files:

```
mkdir Foo
cd Foo
xar -xf ../Foo.pkg
cd foo.pkg
cat Payload | gunzip -dc |cpio -i
# edit Foo.app/*
rm Payload
find ./Foo.app | cpio -o | gzip -c > Payload
mkbom Foo.app Bom # or edit Bom
# edit PackageInfo
rm -rf Foo.app
cd ..
xar -cf ../Foo-new.pkg
```

I believe you can get mkbom (and lsbom) for most linux distros. (If you can get ditto, that makes things even easier, but I'm not sure if that's nearly as ubiquitously available.)

Comment: Yes. I have tried this method before (only unpack/pack without changing any files), but after installed this pkg nothing happend. In console I got this message:
    posix_spawn("/Library/Application Support/Project1/Project1.app/Contents/MacOS/Project1", ...): No such file or directory.

I have investigated that old Payload file has /./Project1.app/... and new payload has /Project1.app/... inside.

Comment: Well, that last part is easy. I don't know if it makes a difference, but it might (maybe because the Bom and the Payload don't match?). Just use ./Foo.app instead of Foo.app in the find|cpio|gzip command. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @abarnert: instead of `cat Payload | gunzip -dc |cpio -i` you could simply use `tar xzvf Payload`

Comment: I get an error running `cat Payload | gunzip -dc |cpio -i`: `gunzip: unknown compression format`;`0 blocks`. I'm trying to open `BSD.pkg` from OS X Yosemite installation package.

Comment: @ccpizza Your suggestion also doesn't work, I get: `tar: Unrecognized archive format`;`tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`.

Comment: @shrx: It's possible that Apple has extended the `.pkg` format in 10.10, or that this is not actually a package file (there are two other file types plus a directory bundle type that can be given the `.pkg` or `.mpkg` extension and work…).

Comment: @ccpizza: New BSD `tar` can handle cpio transparently. (It can also handle gzip transparently, so you can just use `xvf` without the `z`.) But I don't think GNU `tar` can, and I think many linux distros still use GNU `tar`. (Old BSD and SysV `tar` definitely can't handle `cpio`, but those are less likely to be an issue for Linux users…)

Comment: @abarnert this particular `.pkg` was extractable with this method at least in 10.7, so it should still be a package. Looks like a change in format.

Comment: @shrx: It sounds like you want to create a new question asking about how Apple has changed their pkg format in 10.10 and how you can deal with it (along with whatever information, links, etc. you have). If it's documented and you can't find it by searching, someone else will. If it's not documented, someone will reverse engineer it.

Comment: I didn't have xar so I tried: `7z x <file>.pkg` and it worked.

Comment: hey @abarnert, I am trying this. But even if I just use xar unpack the .pkg file, change NOTHING, and use xar -cf pack it again. The package file is not ok to install, when I try to install it on mac, I got 'com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1' 
could you please suggest on this?

Comment: when i tape : xar -cf ../new_name.pkg i had this error : xar -cf new_name.pkg
Usage: xar -[ctx][v] -f <archive> ...

Comment: I was able rename a .pkg to .zip in windows 7 and then extract it.

Answer (score 32):

Here is a bash script inspired by [abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299907/191246) which will unpack a package named `MyPackage.pkg` into a subfolder named `MyPackage_pkg` and then open the folder in Finder.

```sh
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    filename="$*"
    dirname="${filename/\./_}"
    pkgutil --expand "$filename" "$dirname"
    cd "$dirname"
    tar xvf Payload
    open .
```

Usage:

```
    pkg-upack.sh MyPackage.pkg
```

> Warning: This will not work in all cases, and will fail with certain files, e.g. the PKGs inside the OSX system installer. If you want to peek inside the pkg file and see what's inside, you can try [SuspiciousPackage](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) (free app), and if you need more options such as selectively unpacking specific files, then have a look at [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) (nagware).

Comment: Use pbzx -n macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload | cpio -i for newer archives (taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41598227/5688277)

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look into my fork of `pbzx` here: https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/pbzx

It allows you to stream pbzx files that are not wrapped in a XAR archive. I've experienced this with recent XCode Command-Line Tools Disk Images (eg. 10.12 XCode 8).

```
pbzx -n Payload | cpio -i
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @abarnert said, I today had to find out that the default `cpio` utility on Mountain Lion uses a different archive format per default (not sure which), even with the man page stating it would use the old cpio/odc format. So, if anyone stumbles upon the `cpio read error: bad file format` message while trying to install his/her manipulated packages, be sure to include the format in the re-pack step:

```
find ./Foo.app | cpio -o --format odc | gzip -c > Payload
```

Answer (score 4):

@shrx I've succeeded to unpack the BSD.pkg (part of the Yosemite installer) by using "pbzx" command.

`pbzx <pkg> | cpio -idmu`

The "pbzx" command can be downloaded from the following link:

- [pbzx Stream Parser](http://www.tonymacx86.com/general-help/135458-pbzx-stream-parser.html)

Answer (score 2):

Bash script to extract pkg: (Inspired by this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950738/16923394)

Save the following code to a file named pkg-upack.sh on the $HOME/Downloads folder

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    filename="$*"
    dirname="${filename/\./_}"
    mkdir "$dirname"
    # pkgutil --expand "$filename" "$dirname"
    xar -xf "$filename" -C "$dirname"
    cd "$dirname"/*.pkg
    pwd
    # tar xvf Payload
    cat Payload | gunzip -dc |cpio -i
    # cd usr/local/bin
    # pwd
    # ls -lt
    # cp -i * $HOME/Downloads/
```

Uncomment the last four lines, if you are using a rudix package.

Usage:

```
    cd $HOME/Downloads
    chmod +x ./pkg-upack.sh
    ./pkg-upack.sh MyPackage.pkg
```

This was tested with the ffmpeg and mawk package from rudix.org (https://rudix.org) search for ffmpeg and mawk packages on this site.

Source : My open source projects : https://sourceforge.net/u/nathan-sr/profile/

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing errors during PKG installation following the accepted answer, I will give you another procedure that worked for me (please note the little changes to xar, cpio and mkbom commands):

```
mkdir Foo
cd Foo
xar -xf ../Foo.pkg
cd foo.pkg
cat Payload | gunzip -dc | cpio -i
# edit Foo.app/*
rm Payload
find ./Foo.app | cpio -o --format odc --owner 0:80 | gzip -c > Payload
mkbom -u 0 -g 80 Foo.app Bom # or edit Bom
# edit PackageInfo
rm -rf Foo.app
cd ..
xar --compression none -cf ../Foo-new.pkg
```

The resulted PKG will have no compression, cpio now uses odc format and specify the owner of the file as well as mkbom.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single - system wide - command in any macOS version after 10.15:

`pkgutil --expand-full <your-package.pk> <output-directory>`

Which will extract the .pkg, all of it's Payloads and all of the contained sub-packages and their payload into <output-directory>.

`--expand-full` has been around for years but isn't listed in the help for `pkgutil`

Answer (score 0):

For those on Linux, as mentioned by @abarnert, the way to extract the `Payload` file using command line is `cat Payload | gunzip -dc |cpio -i`.