# How do I build the Mono MDK on mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mono, mono-mdk

I'm using Xamarin studio to write some C# code on OS X, but I upgraded my computer to OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) developer preview 3, which [breaks](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43070/el-capitan-xcode-7-has-anyone-tried-xamarin-studio-with-it-yet/p2) [mono](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45233/xamarin-studio-on-10-11-beta-3#latest)

As per some of the instructions in those threads, I've compiled mono from source, and it appears to work (I can run mono on the command line, etc), however Xamarin studio does not launch because I don't have Mono.framework in my /Library/Frameworks path. I foolishly uninstalled and tried (and failed) when I first discovered Xamarin not working.

I've looked all over, and I've found plenty of instructions for how to compile Mono itself (done) but nothing which tells me how to build and install Mono.framework

I've also tried installing the Mono MDK from the package, then overwriting it's binaries with my custom built ones, but when I do this Xamarin studio fails to launch telling me I don't have the Mono MDK installed.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: I do not know if they ever released their package scripts... The 'easy' way is to open their existing .pkg for 4.0.2.x, overlay your new files, re-pkg it and run that... there are a number of ways to edit pkgs, here is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298855/how-unpack-and-pack-pkg-file

Comment: Open their pkg and "cat Scripts | gunzip -dc |cpio -i" and look at their postnstall script.. I think that is the one that does the pkgconfig work that Xam-Studio needs

Comment: This is the [extracted Mono.framework](https://www.dropbox.com/s/api23gp0cibxfxr/Mono.framework.tgz?dl=0) from the latest .pkg:  `MonoFramework-MDK-4.3.0.372.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't appear there is a repo available to build/compile the framework from source. The current `Mono MDK package` located [here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) only contains the `Mono.framework` along with the supporting install/uninstall scripts, etc.; current version:

> MonoFramework-MDK-4.0.2.5.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg

The `Mono.framework` should install to `/Library/Frameworks`.

If that is indeed the one you've downloaded and installed I would then verify that it has copied the `Mono.framework` bundle (571.6 MB) into the frameworks directory, open up `Console.app` then launch `Xamarin`. If Xamarin doesn't launch again then I would recommend posting the error message here and proceed from there.

Another option is extract the `Mono.framework` out of the `.pkg` and manually install it.

Answer (score 1):

You might already have found a solution, but in case somebody else finds this thread; Mono has made a preview version that supports El Capitan:

http://www.mono-project.com/download/