# How to unpack pkg file from OSX 10.10 and higher

Tags: macos, pkg-file

I tried to extract Essentials.pkg from OS X 10.10 following by solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299907/751932) answer. But have no success.

I get error `gunzip: unknown compression format` if i try to extract with cmd: `cat Payload | gunzip -dc |cpio -i`

I get error: `tar: Unrecognized archive format` if i try to extract with cmd: `tar xzvf Payload`
Could anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: enter `file Payload` to get the file format.

Comment: @orkoden `Payload: data`

Comment: The use `head Payload` and google for the first couple of magic bits.

Comment: Initial bytes of Payload is `pbzx` - I tried to rename file to Payload.cpio.xz (i googled this extension) and i tried to extract it via GUI - without success too.

Comment: Try [this tool](http://www.tonymacx86.com/general-help/135458-pbzx-stream-parser.html)

Comment: Thanks! I compiled this tool with `gcc -llzma -lxar pbzx.c` and successfully extract with it.