# How to extract contents from 'Payload' file in a apple macOS update package?

Tags: macos

I am extracting macOS sierra update package - `macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg` using following command to /tmp/macosupd directory.

```
pkgutil --expand /Volumes/macOS\ Sierra\ Update/macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg /tmp/macosupd
```

I can see following packages are bundled inside the metapackage.

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1  Distribution
drwxr-xr-x   6  FirmwareUpdate.pkg
drwxr-xr-x   5  FullBundleUpdate.pkg
drwxr-xr-x  36  Resources
drwxr-xr-x   6  macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg
```

I am not able to extract contents of Payload file. For example when i try to extract the Payload of macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg, i get following error message:

with tar:

```
tar -xvf macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload 
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

with xar:

```
xar -xvf macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload 
Error opening xar archive: macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload
```

When I run file command on the payload file, i get a message as:

```
file macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload 
macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload: data
```

By seeing initial bits of Payload file using `xxd` command , i can see file type looks like `pbzx`

```
xxd macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload 


00000000: 7062 7a78 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  pbzx............
00000010: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0031 0330 fd37 7a58  .........1.0.7zX
00000020: 5a00 0000 ff12 d941 04c0 f385 c401 8080  Z......A........
00000030: 8008 2101 1600 0000 506a 84e2 e3b8 13ef  ..!.....Pj......
00000040: fe5d 0018 0ddf 07a4 347c 7c50 9853 8031  .]......4||P.S.1
00000050: 2d14 f703 6903 cf69 f214 76b0 93c0 a4c9  -...i..i..v.....
00000060: 774d 6fb0 8b3a 2257 4a55 04ad 289b cc4d  wMo..:"WJU..(..M
00000070: b835 5db7 7e72 f7a8 dc15 7a9c 7755 800c  .5].~r....z.wU..
00000080: 6060 d45f e078 f84f e537 4319 2d89 f72e  ``._.x.O.7C.-...
00000090: 60c4 cdb0 6b54 9326 9321 3339 4a4f 1e75  `...kT.&.!39JO.u
000000a0: 8eb7 991d 8968 5e6f 45d4 24c9 e364 712b  .....h^oE.$..dq+
000000b0: ef4e 9abc af70 e97a e5a3 1810 7f05 54df  .N...p.z......T.
000000c0: 08d2 3060 9f8a a1e0 edb8 2b10 df23 789d  ..0`......+..#x.
000000d0: 3e52 ee3e d6f0 468a bfee 3366 d39e 28db  >R.>..F...3f..(.
```

Please suggest a way on how to extract the contents of `Payload` file. I have tried all he methods suggested in [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298855/how-to-unpack-and-pack-pkg-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989912/how-to-unpack-pkg-file-from-osx-10-10-and-higher), including the method suggested in this [external-link](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/pbzx-stream-parser.135458/)  still no success. Seems like apple updates prior to Mavericks were pure xar and tar packages. With Mavericks and above apple changed the file format from a tar to pbzx(lzma).

please suggest an easy command line way to extract contents of the `Payload` file as i have to make use in my automation setup.

Answer (score 102):

There is an undocumented option to `pkgutil`, `--expand-full`, which uses the same syntax as `pkgutil --expand`.

`pkgutil --expand-full [pkg] [dir]`

This will completely "unarchive" a pkg or mpkg file.

Comment: Very useful! Thank you.

Comment: Determine type of the archive and use the appropriate unarchiver instead.

Comment: @georgexsh No, it hasn't — I just didn't correctly have the syntax marked that a second argument (where to extract) was needed. Fixed.

Comment: Worked like a charm in osX 10.14 Mojave.
Make sure the destination [dir] does not exist. pkgutil will create that.

Comment: This worked for me to extract macOS 10.12 installer contents.

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.5, successfully extracted JDK7 package. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about macOS 11+, but it worked on 10.15.17.

Answer (score 19):

Since OSX 10.10, the `Payload` in the `.pkg` files is encoded as `pbzx` (which is in turn lzma compressed). It can no longer be extracted using `gunzip`. Check out the [pbzx tool](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/pbzx) (a fork of the [original](http://www.tonymacx86.com/general-help/135458-pbzx-stream-parser.html) which would not allow you to extract the Payload directly but only by passing the `.pkg` file directly).

Instead of

```
tar -xvf macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload
```

you can write

```
pbzx -n macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg/Payload | cpio -i
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped.

Comment: The "macOSUpd10.12.1.pkg" represents the name of the folder where the pkg was extracted into, right? It was a bit confusing to me at first glance, I thought pbzx was able to "look into" the pkg file and only extract the "Payload".

Comment: I've seen some PKGs (Avast antivirus, for example) that have CPIO format Payload file. Is CPIO considered to be lzma-compressed pbzx? I thought that CPIO utilizes no compression.