# Creating a .pkg file on a javascript website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, pkgbuild, pkg-file

I can't seem to figure out a way to convert files from my AWS S3 to a .pkg file on a javascript website. The files will be converted and uploaded back to AWS as a pkg. Does anyone know how to do this all online, either server side or with javascript? Thanks!

Comment: You did not explain where the problem is? What you have tried and what did not work?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I'm not sure how to go about converting the files to a pkg.

Comment: What kind of .pkg file do you have in mind? There's a number of different file types which all use that extension.

Comment: An OSX flat package

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298855/how-to-unpack-and-pack-pkg-file