# MacOSX Encrypted Installer .pkg

Tags: macos

I'm Downloaded this files but not opening with pkgutil My Question is how to decrypt and extract pkg file and get InstallESD.dmg pls help me Sorry for my bad engllish ;)

http://osxapps.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/Purple49/v4/15/89/37/1589378d-0b6e-ef90-5533-b2f3bb2fe491/encrypted1202238309850061611.pfpkg

http://osxapps.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/Purple69/v4/61/cb/04/61cb0419-ba73-70c1-02ce-b1cee2f2269c/encrypted8769637421434146660.pkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents are encrypted there is no hope unless you have the key, that is the whole point of encryption.

To examine and open .pkg files Use ["Pacifist.app"](https://www.charlessoft.com).

The file `encrypted1202238309850061611.pfpkg` is not encrypted, I can tell by looking at the contents in a hex editor, there may be sub portions that are though. If you change the extension from `pfpkg` to `pkg` Pacifist will open it.

The file `encrypted1202238309850061611.pkg` will open in Pacifist.

See [How to unpack and pack pkg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298855/how-to-unpack-and-pack-pkg-file#11299907).

Comment: but this pkg file not opening with Pacifist.app and pkg file is encrypted

Comment: The files are openable in Pacifist see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! but encrypted8769637421434146660.pkg don't opening with Pacifist app